# Can I import an APIM hosted from outside Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

## A Little Background

I'm currently attempting to set up an API Manager to handle authorization in Azure in a mixed cloud environment (AWS and Azure) as per [the MSDN doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#enable-oauth-20-user-authorization-in-the-developer-console)

## Our Environment

We are using both AWS and Azure and as of now have EC2 instances with our API. Our API also has swagger and should meet the conventions required for the importer.

The API is an ASP.NET WebApi2 (Full Framework version) and is configured with swagger. Also, the ec2 api endpoint can be seen from Azure as we are using Azure Active Directory app registrations to authenticate our apps.

## The Rub

Currently, I can't test this as I have limited permissions to the Azure environment and am awaiting approval but, I am being asked to explore this. (You just gotta love the bureaucracy) Otherwise, we will be implementing OWIN and adal.js for service to service and service to client communications and would not be the preferred way to go. [See this MSDN article for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)

## The Ask

Is it possible or should I just set expectations to go the hard route?
Can I import an APIM hosted from outside Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.

Just import the swagger and add your (public) backend URL —

[image: Swagger import]

To authenticate calls between API Management and the external API, i see three immediate approaches:

- [Integrate API Management with a VNET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet) and call the external API over site-to-site VPN (this alleviates the need to do OAuth but requires non-trivial infrastructure setup effort). Well, non-trivial but not horrible, just look at this StrongSwan configuration:

  ```
  conn azure
      authby=secret
      type=tunnel
      leftsendcert=never
      left=40.127.x.x
      leftsubnet=10.5.5.0/24
      right=172.31.22.44
      rightsubnet=10.77.0.0/16
      keyexchange=ikev2
      auto=start
  ```
- Use OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant. This is referred to as [Web App to Web API in Azure AD docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api). I believe [this is the relevant API Management guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad). The API Management instance becomes the confidential client in this case (holds client_id and client_secret), acquires a Bearer (access) token and calls the external API by including it in the `Authorization` header.
- Use a shared secret between API Management and your external API. Not the most secure thing in the world (it won't expire every hour like a JWT does) but not unheard of. It's an *API key* way of dealing with the problem, kind of a Diffie-Hellman key exchange without Diffie, or Hellman or [Merkle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Merkle). Just Alice and Bob sharing a secret :)

Use HTTPS everywhere, yes even across the VPN - think request headers/body immutability rather than added security. People like to deploy contraptions that "inspect" stuff...